# Antlr4 token existence messing up parsing

Tags: parsing, logging, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4

first time poster so my greatest apologies if I break the rules.
I'm using Antlr4 to create a log parser and I'm running into some issues that I don't understand.

I'm trying to parse the following input log sequence:

```
USA1-RR-SRX240-EDGE-01 created 10.20.30.40/50985->11.12.13.14/443
```

With the following grammar:

```
grammar Juniper;

WS : (' '|'\t')+ -> skip ;
NL : '\r'? '\n' -> skip ;
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9' ;
NUMBER : DIGIT+ ;
IPADDRESS : NUMBER '.' NUMBER '.' NUMBER '.' NUMBER ;
SLASH : '/' -> skip ;
RIGHTARROW : '->' -> skip ;
CREATED: 'created' -> skip ;
HOSTNAME : [a-zA-Z0-9\-]+ ;

/* Input sample for rule: USA1-RR-SRX240-EDGE-01 created 10.20.30.40/50985->11.12.13.14/443 */
testcase : HOSTNAME WS CREATED WS IPADDRESS SLASH NUMBER RIGHTARROW IPADDRESS SLASH NUMBER NL;
```

It's failing and I can't for the life of me figure out why.  I know that the token recognition error has something to do with the token that I've defined for HOSTNAME containing the dash in the character class but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
$ antlr4 Juniper.g4 && javac Juniper*.java && grun Juniper testcase -tree
USA1-RR-SRX240-EDGE-01 created 10.20.30.40/50985->11.12.13.14/443
line 1:48 token recognition error at: '>'
line 1:30 mismatched input '10.20.30.40' expecting WS
(testcase SA1-RR-SRX240-EDGE-01 10.20.30.40 50985- 11.12.13.14 443)
```

Please note the second line of the above output is data that I paste into grun and then hit enter and hit control+D.

Any assistance on this would be highly appreciated, been banging me head against the keyboard on this for a bit now.

Comment: Realizing there is a gap in my understanding as the lexer makes a first pass and skip in the lexer rule means that the parser doesn't see it at all.

Comment: Right, if you want the parser to see a token, don't use skip. Or if you want to skip the characters (as with whitespace), don't put the WS token into your grammar.

Comment: I don't know that much about ANTLR; it's possible that it includes some feature for this type of parsing. Personally, I'd use a different mechanism to analyze the log files (perhaps just a regular expression, followed by analysis of the captures), but you could also consider a custom lexer class which keeps track of context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with recognizing `->` is that HOSTNAME matches any sequence of letters, numbers and dashes, and that includes `50985-`. Since that match is longer than what NUMBER would match (`50985`), HOSTNAME wins. That's evidently not what you want.

Parsing log lines generally requires a context-sensitive scanner, and standard parser generators -- which are more oriented towards parsing programming languages -- are not always the ideal tool. In this case, for example, HOSTNAME cannot appear in the context in which it is being recognized, so it shouldn't even be in the list of possible tokens.

Of course, you could define a token which consisted of an ip number and port separated by a slash, which would solve the ambiguity, but (in my opinion) that would be suboptimal because you'll end up rescanning that token to parse it.

Comment: Are there any awesome toolkits like Antlr for context-sensitive scanners that you would recommend beside logstash?

Comment: @zach: I don't do much java, so I'm not really al tanto with java toolkits. Sorry. I'm sure google will help you find something, but you may well be able to just take the lines apart with a regex. Depends on how complicated the full log format is. It's a shame that structured logging is so rare :(